# datatables clear search content in filter without seting statesave to false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
$("#table-list").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"

  });
```

I have used datatables in my RAILS aplication.
Here suppose the user is on page 3 ,even after refreshing i need it to be on page 3..but i want the content in the filter to be removed.
setting stateSave will let my pagination work..
but it will not claer the content in the search bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [stateSaveParams](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveParams) to only load what you want.

```
$("#table-list").dataTable({
   "bJQueryUI": true,
   "bStateSave": true,
   "bFilter": true,
   "bInfo": true,
   "bSort": true,
   "bPaginate": true,
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
   "sstateSaveParams": function (settings, data) {
      data.search.search = "";
      }
```

});